Arm IK bone constraints problem
I'm new to blender, I'm having problems moving this arm properly using IK bone constraints, instead of the arm moving with the large bones it bends on the smaller bones which are for rotations. is there a way for me to make the small bones (for rotation) follow the Large bones (for movement) using IK?
the model is a premade model from Playbox
the 1st image highlights the small bones for rotation
2nd image highlights the big bones for movement
3rd image highlights the unwanted bending on the small bones
4th image is how I want the bones to act





It appears that the parenting hiearchy of the bones is incorrect. In the second image, it is clear that the forearm bone is not a connected child of the upper arm bone like it should be. It seems to be a child of the upper arm twisting bone instead. The twisting bones should have no children, and should themselves be disconnected children of whatever limb segment they are twisting. Read about how to change bone parents here.
